# fill null values by joining dataframe with different number of rows and on multiple column

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've tried to search but although I got similar scenarios I didn't find what I was looking for.

I have the following two dataframes:

```
+---------------------------+
|   ID|       Value|   type |
+---------------------------+
|  user0|     100  |   Car  |
|  user1|     102  |   Car  |
|  user2|     109  |   Dog  |
|  user3|     103  |   NA   |
|  user4|     110  |   Dog  |
|  user5|     null |   null |
|  user6|     null |   null |
|  user7|     null |   null |
+---------------------------+

+---------------------------+
|   ID2|     Value2|  type2|
+---------------------------+
|  user5|     115  |  Cell  |
|  user6|     103  |  Cell  |
|  user7|     100  |  Fridge|
+---------------------------+
```

I'd like to join those two and have this as result:

```
+---------------------------+
|   ID|       Value|   type |
+---------------------------+
|  user0|     100  |   Car  |
|  user1|     102  |   Car  |
|  user2|     109  |   Dog  |
|  user3|     103  |   NA   |
|  user4|     110  |   Dog  |
|  user5|     115  |   Cell |
|  user6|     103  |   Cell |
|  user7|     100  | Fridge |
+---------------------------+
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't give back the desired results:

```
df_joined= df1.join(df2,(df1.id==df2.id2) &
                      (df1.value==df2.value2) &
                     (df1.type==df2.type2),
                      "left").drop('id2','value2','type2')
```

I only get the values from the first df, probably left is not the right join type but I can't understand what should I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join using ID, not the other columns, because the other columns are not the same. To combine the other columns, use `coalesce`, which gives the first non-null value.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_joined = df1.join(df2, df1.ID == df2.ID2, 'left').select(
    'ID',
    F.coalesce(df1.Value, df2.Value2).alias('Value'),
    F.coalesce(df1.type, df2.type2).alias('type')
)

df_joined.show()
+-----+-----+------+
|   ID|Value|  type|
+-----+-----+------+
|user0|  100|   Car|
|user1|  102|   Car|
|user2|  109|   Dog|
|user3|  103|    NA|
|user4|  110|   Dog|
|user5|  115|  Cell|
|user6|  103|  Cell|
|user7|  100|Fridge|
+-----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use union then get the max :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df1.union(df2).groupBy("ID").agg(
    F.max("value").alias("value"),
    F.max("type").alias("type")
)

result.show()
#+-----+-----+------+
#|   ID|value|  type|
#+-----+-----+------+
#|user0|  100|   Car|
#|user1|  102|   Car|
#|user2|  109|   Dog|
#|user3|  103|    NA|
#|user4|  110|   Dog|
#|user5|  115|  Cell|
#|user6|  103|  Cell|
#|user7|  100|Fridge|
#+-----+-----+------+
```